# How can I change the fragment in running?

Tags: android, fragment

Hy, I have this code in my Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_menu,container,false);
      final ViewGroup dismissableContainer = (ViewGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.dismissable_container);
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         final Button dismissableButton = new Button(getActivity());
          dismissableButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          dismissableButton.setText("Button " + (i + 1));

      dismissableContainer.addView(dismissableButton);

      }




       return view;
   }
```

in the same fragment I have a method that receives an object from the outside

```
 public void sendObject(MyObject t){

         Button b=new Button(getActivity());
         b.setText(t.getNum_tav());


     // Now I want to put **b** under  button1 button2 and button3 

   }
```

in the method sendobject ... How can I change the fragment?
I have to put the button with the other 3 button

Comment: Make dismissableContainer a field and then just add to that whenever you need.

Comment: same problem, look below

Comment: im assuming you are trying to modify the view in a different thread

Comment: no is always in the same fragment.. in sendObject

Comment: what calls sendObject ?

Comment: is called from an external method to send at the fragment this object

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the same `ViewGroup`, assuming it's a vertical `LinearLayout`:

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.dismissable_container).addView(b);
```

If it's not, then you'll have to work out the layout to prepare a suitable position for it, but it should be conceptually similar.